Tautomerism in para benzoquinone
Does tautomerism exist in para benzoquinone? If not why? I have seen an explanation that relates it to alpha hydrogens but couldn't understand it.

What kind of tautomerism would you expect here?

Try to draw the enol structure. You have two cumulated double bonds at one carbon, so the bond angle at that carbon has to be close to 180° to form good bonds there, and that creates a problem in the six-membered ring.
